# Using Maple to numerically find the unique extremum ("turning point") of a given function

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, maple

> Given
>   $$
> f(x) = 5\sin\left(\frac14 x^4\right) -\sin\left(\frac12 x\right)^4
> $$
>   Find, to 10 significant figures, the unique turning point  of x[0] in the interval [1,2].

Also, I've got to get the second derivative in 10 significant figures.

The plot doesn't exactly make sense in maple, don't think I understand how to go about solving it mathematically.

[original image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Pb5m.gif)

Comment: Also, you will need the definition of "turning point" and the connection between $x$ and $\mathtt{x[0]}$.

Answer (score 1):

If by "turning point" you mean relative extrema, then the only relative max on your interval is located at $x \approx 1.576726466$.

> [> f := x -> 5*sin(x^4/4)-sin(x/2)^4;
>   [> plot(f(x),x=1..2);

[image: plot of f(x)]

Setting $f'(x)=0$ and solving we get...

> [> x[0] := fsolve(diff(f(x),x)=0,x=1.6);

```
                      1.576726466
```

Plugging this into the second derivative we get...

> [> evalf(subs(x=x[0],diff(f(x),x,x)));

```
                      -76.34072337
```

Answer (score 0):

$\tt fsolve(diff(5*sin(x^4/4)-sin(x/2)^4, x\$2), x, 1 .. 2)$ gives 1.321411467.